# Создание экземпляра класса, независимого от других объектов

Tags: delphi, классы, delphi-7

Здравствуйте. Создаю экземпляр по такой схеме:

```
    type
      TExercise = object;

    var
      TMyExercise: TExercise;
```

Получается что я могу не объявлять переменные на форме для создания экземпляра класса и обращаться к объекту без ссылок на форму(если бы я создал из нее). Так же это позволяет мне иметь единственный экземпляр, в котором хранятся нужные мне данные, используемые несколькими формами.

Но так создают из-за обратной совместимости, судя по справке.

Есть ли другой способ создавать независимый от других объектов класс в Borland Delphi 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*В Delphi обычно не принято называть переменные с большой буквой `T` в начале, поскольку такая буква в начале литерала обычно говорит о том, что это тип (от англ. type, например: `TExercise`, `TObject`, `TStringList` и т.д.). Так удобнее читать код, даже свой :)*

Обычно класс объявляется, например, так:

```
TExercise = class(TObject)
private
  FMyInt: Integer;
  FMyString: string;
public
  property Int: Integer read FMyInt write FMyInt;
  property Str: string read FMyString; // только для чтения
end;
```

Для того, чтобы создать экземпляр класса, нужно вызвать его конструктор:

```
MyExercise := TExercise.Create;
```

Когда работа с объектом окончена и он больше не нужен, **обязательно нужно освободить память** занимаемую объектом:

```
MyExercise.Free;
```

Иначе будут утечки памяти и она рано или поздно закончится.

---

Для создания "по-быстрому" независимого глобального объекта для использования на разных формах можно сделать так:

```
unit UnitExercise;

interface

type
  TExercise = class(TObject)
  private
    MyInt: Integer;
    MyString: string;
  public
    property Int: Integer read MyInt write MyInt;
    property Str: string read MyString; // только для чтения
  end;

var
  MyExercise: TExercise;

implementation

initialization
  MyExercise := TExercise.Create;

finalization
  MyExercise.Free;

end.
```

И добавить модуль `UnitExercise` в список используемых модулей (`uses`) в те модули, в которых предполагается использование этого объекта.

**Однако, в такой конструкции есть недостаток:** вы практически не контролируете порядок создания и уничтожения таких объектов (если их много, они в разных модулях и еще зависят друг от друга), что может быть актуально для больших проектов. Управлять порядком вызова секций `initialization` и `finalization` можно, меняя порядок объявления модулей в проекте и его модулях, но это очень сложная эквилибристика. Если интересно, то это тема для отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо за информативный ответ, про литерал T знаю, просто в этом примере была копипаста старого наброска)

Благодаря вашему ответу нашел на просторах интернета своеобразную реализацию паттерна Одиночка(Singleton) на Delphi.
[Ссылка на реализацию паттерна](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/delphi)